# Cómo reemplazar todo el documento?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, que detalladamente describo en él mismo, mi finalidad al realizar este código es que en la web, **cualquier elemento con acentos sea reemplazado** por su código en `html`, por ejemplo:

`"ó" por "&oacute"` ,

Mis problema es que al guardar todo el texto del html **en una variable** y luego al intentar reemplazar los caracteres con `replace(regex, "replace");` , **no los reemplaza** y además suponiendo que lograse reemplazarlos, **como podría reemplazarlos en el documento**? ya que con `innerHTML`, **se borraría todo**..

> *Entonces, cuál es mi error?, por qué no está funcionando?*

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  console.log(utf8());
});

function utf8(){
  let i = 0;
  let elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("*"));     /*
  Obtengo todo el documento y array.from para usar metodos de la  
  clase array de ser necesario.
  */
  let max = elements.length; 
  var nuevoDocument = ""; // aquí guardaré todo el documento reemplazado 
  for(;i<max;i++){ // recorro los tags
  let n = elements[i]; // los guardo
  nuevoDocument += n.textContent.replace(/áéíóúñ/ig,"&"+n.textContent.match(/áéíóúñ/i)+"acute");
  /* Aquí esta varible será igual a todo el texto, pero reemplazando las letras áéíóuñ por su caracter en html, cómo?
  buscando donde coincidió con:
  
 "&" +  n.textContent.match(/áéíóúñ/i) + "acute" 
 
 Entonces por ejemplo quedaría: 
 
 "ó" reemplazado por: "&oacute" 
  */
  }
  return nuevoDocument; // retorno la variable.
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <i> holaa!</i>
  <BR>
  <b> como estás</i>
    <BR>
  <b> bien y tú</i>
      <hr></hr>
  <footer>EN ACCIÓN!</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que pueda mostrar el reemplazo, hay que cambiar `utf8();` por `document.body.innerHTML=utf8()`.

Nota: En *JavaScript*, casi no es necesario usar el punto y coma. Solo en algunas ocasiones es necesario insertarlo en el código.

Hice una función que reemplaza las tildes con expresiones regulares, pero para esto, en vez de una sola expresión regular para todas las tildes, es necesario ejecutar la expresión regular en cada caracter.

Lo que hace la expresión es recorrer iterar 5 veces, una vez para cada vocal. Declaro dos array para las minúsculas, y dos arrays para las mayúsculas, y el `for` se encarga de hacer los reemplazos.

- Minúsculas, ingreso: `áéíóú`
- Minúsculas, reemplazo: `aeiou`
- Mayúsculas, ingreso: `ÁÉÍÓÚ`
- Mayúsculas, reemplazo: `AEIOU`

Ya que lo hago de esta manera, el modificador `i` de la expresión regular, ya no está más, porque ahora es sensible a mayúsculas.

El siguiente código funciona bien, salvo en caso de que existan tildes en los atributos del *HTML*. Hacerlo con `textContent` se me hace demasiado complicado, pero estoy seguro que se puede.

Si se quiere reemplazar la Ñ y otros, dejo este enlace interesante, que tiene una tabla con todos los caracteres *ASCII*: https://ascii.cl/es/codigos-html.htm

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  document.body.innerHTML=utf8()
});

function utf8(){

  var contenido=document.body.innerHTML

  tildes_minúsculas="áéíóú"
  vocales_minúsculas="aeiou"

  tildes_mayúsculas="ÁÉÍÓÚ"
  vocales_mayúsculas="AEIOU"

  for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    var expresión=new RegExp(tildes_minúsculas[i],"g")
    contenido=contenido.replace(expresión,"(&"+vocales_minúsculas[i]+"acute;)")

    var expresión=new RegExp(tildes_mayúsculas[i],"g")
    contenido=contenido.replace(expresión,"(&"+vocales_mayúsculas[i]+"acute;)")
  }
  return contenido
}
```

```html
<i>¡Hola!</i><br/>
<b>¿Cómo estás</b><br/>
<b>Bien, ¿y tú?</b><hr/>
<footer>EN ACCIÓN!</footer>
```